# Shopp plugin in wordpress -to display select box of shipping method

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, shopp

I'm new to WordPress and a very new to "shopp plugin",
I want to select box that displays shipping method

```
shopp('shipping', 'option-menu', 'difference=on');
```

This doesn't work. Please tell me in details about how to fetch this shipping method data using above  code and where to look after the code for further changes to get the select box with details comes by OrderAmount-0, ItemQuantity-0 filling from [shipping menu] present in [system] side menu.

Comment: Where are you displaying this code? Shipping methods should appear on checkout once you have set them in Shopp->settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<?php if ( shopp('shipping', 'has-options') ): ?>
    <?php while ( shopp('shipping','options')): 
    $selected = ''; 
    if ( shopp('shipping','option-selected') ) 
        $selected = ' selected="selected"';
    $value = shopp('shipping','get-option-slug');
    $name = shopp('shipping','get-option-name');
    $cost = shopp('shipping','get-option-cost);
    $delivery = shopp('shipping', 'get-option-delivery');
    $label = $name.' &mdash '.$cost.' '.$delivery;
    ?>

    <select name="shipmethod" class="shopp shipmethod">
    <option value="<?php echo $value; ?>"<?php echo $selected; ?> ><?php echo $label; ?></option>
    </select>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply but it does nt worked for me .....please explain me in details

Comment: There is a typo in this code. `get-option-cost` is missing a `'`